# Why is solving linear equation system so fundamental to applied mathematics?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

They appear as a subroutine in nearly every algorithm, which solves a complex applied mathematical problem. Examples are finite elements, newton method, simplex method, interior point method, regression .... Is there an explanation, why this structure appears over and over again?

Comment: It's almost the only thing that's easy to do. Most other things are very difficult.

Comment: You beat me to making this point, by 26 seconds!

Comment: Linear equations are solvable unlike most systems of equations so they tend to be computationally fruitful. Many problems in math are only tractable because linear approximations and methods can be extended to non-linear systems. So even when the problem isn't linear, we may be able to linearize it in a meaningful way to get an answer that's good enough for application.